# What's the difference between these two definitions of ‘determination’?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

These are two definitions for the noun "determination" from the same dictionary ([American Heritage® Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/determination)). One was right below the other. Is it me or you could basically combine these two definitions (2.a with 3.b & 2.b with 3.b) into one and there isn't any real difference between them?

> DETERMINATION
> **2. a.** The ascertaining or fixing of the quantity, quality, position, or character of something: a determination of the ship's longitude; a determination of the universe's mass.
> **b.** The result of such ascertaining.
> **3. a.** The act of making or arriving at a decision: After long determination, she decided to move to Utah.
> **b.** The decision reached: It is my determination to sell the house.
> See Synonyms at *decision*.

Comment: I find both the uses in 3 to be odd. I would expect to find them only in old writing.

Comment: 3b is better explained by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/determination) i.e. *firm or fixed intention to achieve a desired end*. Examples: (1) She was  a woman of great courage and determination, (2) With fierce determination, working as a housemaid to support herself, she completed secondary education equivalency..

Comment: @ColinFine - I have come across it in current UK legal contexts, e.g. a court or tribunal can make a determination about something, e.g.  an application by somebody, and, in civil law,  'expert determination' is a binding dispute resolution process which can resolve disputes faster and more cheaply than the courts or formal arbitration.

Comment: @Graffito The word "determination" in a sense of "firm intention" has nothing to do with the definitions I provided in this post. At least, I think this to be the case. Can anyone confirm or disprove this?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, OK, old writing or legalese. Or officialese.

Comment: @StaticBounce: I agree that the "firm intention" meaning is quite separate.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between 2a and 3b can be illustrated using the verb *determine*, which has meanings parallel to them. Consider

> How did paleontologists **determine** the age of the fossil?

and

> How did the judge **determine** that five years was the appropriate sentence?

In the former, *determine* means discover, work out, learn. In the latter, *determine* means reach a decision. The first sense of *determine* involves finding an answer that, in some sense, is already out there awaiting discovery; the second sense is more like creating an answer as the result of judgement and possibly opinion.

Comment: I've got a gut feeling that this answer is correct but It would be nice if some people upvoted it or confirmed it.

Comment: In the UK, judges in criminal courts determine sentences by referring to sentencing guidelines. Parliament sets the maximum (and sometimes minimum) penalty for any offence. When deciding the appropriate sentence, the court must follow any relevant sentencing guidelines, unless it is not in the interests of justice to do so. E.g. the maximum sentence for theft of goods worth less than £200 is six months, and if more, seven years. Sentences are calculated by an assessment of culpability and harm.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly true that there is a close connection between definitions 2a and 2b, but they are not the same and cannot be merged.

To grasp this you need to understand that **determine** (the verb) has one basic meaning, but **determination** (the related noun) has two different meanings.

For simplicity, let's say that "**to determine**" means to work out an answer to something. **Determination** will then mean both the process of working out the answer, and the answer itself.

Consider the dictionary example above, the determination of a ship's longitude [its position on the surface of the earth]. We could say this:

- The ship's captain used his GPS system to determine the longitude of his ship; he determined that it was 45 degrees East.

In this example, **determination** now has a double focus. It describes the method by which the longitude was calculated (using the ship's GPS system). It also refers to the resulting answer (45 degrees East).

It's worth noting that other English words follow the same pattern. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calculation) defines **calculation** in exactly the same dual way:

1a. the process or an act of calculating
1b. the result of an act of calculating